# How to set cool downs for buttons trigger zones

Tags: rec-room

Mainly want to set a cool down period to prevent people from buying weapons twice accidentally while using a trigger zone.

I'm assuming there's a timer chip and a comparer chip in here somewhere, I just can't figure out the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you can do this, each having tradeoffs of complexity and ink cost.

### Timer Chip Method

This circuit gives the button a 10 tick cooldown configured on the green pin of the Timer chip.

[image: Timer Chip Method]

**Notes:**

- Cheapest cooldown circuit possible currently.
- Reliable; it should always recover from any reasonable circuit glitches
- Can have a dynamic cooldown by connecting the green pin of the timer chip to some circuit logic.
- Cooldown can be activated from multiple sources by simply plugging each one into the OR chip.
- Cannot be reset without an additional chip.

### State Machine Method

This circuit relies on the "Minimum Time In State" setting on the `Cool` state. Configure the cooldown duration in the `Cool` state.

[image: State Machine Method]

**Notes:**

- One chip more expensive than the Timer Chip Method
- Cannot change cooldown duration dynamically with circuits
- Easily add indicators for a cooldown by utilizing the variables stored in states. For instance, change text to red when the button is on cooldown.
- The circuit can be reset with the Reset pin of the State Machine which might be useful when dealing with long cooldowns.

### Combined Timer and State Machine

If you wish to apply cooldowns to particular pathways in a complex state machine, or if you wish to just simply have a dynamic cooldown time for the state machine method, this circuit will achieve that.

[image: Combined State and Timer Method]

**Notes:**

- Is two chips more expensive than the Timer Chip Method
- Has all the benefits of the State Machine Method and some of the benefits of the Timer Chip Method
- Can be used on arbitrary edges in a larger state machine to manage complex cooldowns. For instance, this might be used to manage the cooldowns for a player's various special abilities.

All of these circuits are available for you to tinker with [here](https://rrcs.tk/circuit/sulxSyMXm).